# React/TypeScript component library - implement subpaths import?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack

i've created a component library (React, TypeScript and Webpack) that has a structure that looks like this:

```
- src
  - ui-components
      - ComponentA
      - ComponentB
      - index.ts
  - plugins
      - PluginA
      - PluginB
      - index.ts
  - index.ts
```

`src/index.ts` looks like this:

```
export * from './ui-components';
export * from './plugins';
```

`src/ui-components/index.ts` looks like this:

```
export * from './ComponentA';
export * from './ComponentB';
```

`src/plugins/index.ts` looks like this:

```
export * from './PluginA';
export * from './PluginB';
```

My `package.json` looks like this:

```
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist/**"
  ],
  "exports": {
    "./ui-components": {
        "import": "./dist/ui-components/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./plugins": {
      "import": "./dist/plugins/index.d.ts"
  }
```

However, when i import this library to a new project, the only way i can seem to import the ui-components and plugins is by:

```
import { ComponentA } from 'myLibrary';
```

or:

```
import { ComponentA } from 'myLibrary/dist/ui-components
```

How could i get my library to be imported like:

```
import { ComponentA } from 'myLibrary/ui-components'
import { PluginA } from 'myLibrary/plugins'
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you have setup typescript to output `js` files in `list` directory. This is why you have to import from `myLibrary/dist/ui-components`.

There are 2 ways you can fix this.

- setup typescript to output to package root. This way there won't be a transient `dist` directory. A you will be able to import directly from `ui-components` directory.
- add an exports map to your package's package.json file that would point `ui-components` to `dist/ui-components/index.js` file. You can read more about exports map [here](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#package-entry-points).